# SQLite selecting multiple sets of rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, limit, where-in

I'm using SQLite, trying to select multiple sets of rows. Example:

```
RowID  USER  Event
------------------
1      Sam   eventX  
2      Sam   eventY
3      Sam   eventA
4      John  E1
5      John  E5
6      Lisa  ev3
7      Lisa  ev4
8      Lisa  ev3
```

I want to select one entry per USER, the one with the highest rowid.
The result set should look like:

```
RowID  USER  Event
------------------
3      Sam   eventA
5      John  E5
8      Lisa  ev3
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Mean and lean:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE RowID IN (
    SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM Table1 GROUP BY User
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Please learn Aggregate function for SQL Lite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_useful_functions.htm)**

```
select max(RowID) as RowID,User,Event
from Table1
group by User
order by max(RowID)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/994d0/7)**

Comment: Why `MAX(Event)`? This will fail if `MAX(Event)` doesn't match row from `MAX(RowID)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(RowID),User,Event from Info group by User order by max(RowID)
```

**Info Table**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rowid, user, event FROM table WHERE rowid IN (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM table GROUP BY user);
```